# A poset that's the union of the lower sets

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset, and let $\downarrow\! p = \{ x\leq p\}\subseteq P$. Let $M\subseteq P$ be the subset of all maximal elements of $P$.

**Question**: is there a specific term for a poset $(P,\leq)$ such that $P \subseteq \bigcup_{m\in M} \downarrow\! m$? That is, $P$ is equal to the union of the lower sets of all maximal elements?

---

If it makes any difference, in my particular case I have that $P = L \setminus \{ \sup L\}$ where $L$ is a complete lattice.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, in the special case you're working with, you're just saying that the lattice $L$ is [coatomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28order_theory%29).

Comment: @Martin: perfect. If you post that as an answer I will accept it (and I can live with reversing my [at present arbitrary choice of] order and make it atomic instead `:p`).

Comment: Only now I realized, that this is (in ZFC) equivalent to (dual of) the condition from Zorn's lemma. (Every chain has a lower bound.) I hope I am not missing something.\\ Since ZL is used so frequently, one would expect for that condition to have a name, but I do not remember seeing it named anywhere.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: to be honest, it has been so long since when I asked the question I can't remember exactly why I asked, and whether ZL was anywhere in the original motivation where I came across sets of this form.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my previous comment. It is true that in an [inductive poset](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inductive_Poset) there exists a maximal element above each element. (For example, see Arturo Magidin's answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23724/).) But these two conditions are clearly not equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a poset $(P,\le)$ then we can adjoin a new greatest element by setting $\overline P=P\cup\{1\}$ and $p\le 1$ for each $p\in P$. As OP mentioned in his post, this is the situation he is working with. (In this case $\overline P$ is the complete lattice $L$.)

In the above situation:

- $m$ is a maximal element of $P$ if and only if $m$ is a [coatom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28order_theory%29) in $\overline P$;
- the condition $P \subseteq \cup_{m\in M} \downarrow\! m$ means that every element of $P$ has a coatom of $\overline P$ above it (this is equivalent to: every element of $P$ has a $P$-maximal element above it).

So together we get that $P$ has the required property if and only if $\overline P$ is coatomic.

The notions of coatom and coatomic poset are dual to the notions of atom and atomic poset. The latter seem to be used more frequently.

---

Based on a guess what phrase could be used if someone would define such thing as described in the question, I browsed a little through the results of searches similar to [poset "minimal element below"](https://www.google.com/search?q=poset+%22minimal+element+below%22). The only thing I found out was that in study of [preference relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preference_%28economics%29) the name smooth relation is used sometimes, e.g.
Coherent systems by Karl Schlechta [p.79](https://books.google.com/books?id=By3cXoqE264C&pg=PA79):

> A strong requirement for the relation, which we find difficult to justify intuitively as a relation property, is smoothness. Essentially, it says that elements are either minimal, or there is a minimal element below them.

Although I do not think this particular case is of much interest for the OP.